# not allowed to send broadcast android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-7.1-nougat

I modified a legacy code where one application sent broadcast message to the second application - widget.
It was OK on API 19, but I've got problem on API 25/Android 7:

> not allowed to send broadcast
>   android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE to
>   com.app.package.balance from com.app.package

I added few strings in manifest, but it didn't help:

```
<application>
  <activity android:name="com.app.package.balance">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE"/>
```

My code (using Appceleration Studio with Titanium SDK):

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createBroadcastIntent({
     action: "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE",
     className: "com.app.package.balance.MyWidget",
     packageName: "com.app.package.balance"
});
Ti.Android.currentActivity.sendBroadcastWithPermission(intent, 'android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE');
```

Same code in Java style:

```
Intent intent4widget= new Intent("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");
intent4widget.setClassName("com.app.package.balance", "com.app.package.balance.MyWidget");
context.sendBroadcast(intent4widget);
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Stop sending that broadcast. Do something else, such as sending a different broadcast action (or, better yet, use an explicit `Intent` rather than an action-based implicit `Intent`). Also `APPWIDGET_UPDATE` is a broadcast action; do not put it on the `<intent-filter>` of an `<activity>`.

Comment: You are right, APPWIDGET_UPDATE forbidden for last Android and I cannot make force update from oneApp to widgetApp. I solved it making my own action - as a result I just transfer data from oneApp to twoApp without force update widget.